# Printing in 3 inches width roll paper in c# using crystal reports

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, crystal-reports

I am working on a POS system in c#. I need to print a bill in the end of  the invoicing. I am using these coding to print directly on button click event with the following codes.

```
 //Print codes to a default printer with my crystal report
 RPT_RetailInvoice objRpt = new RPT_RetailInvoice();
 objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);
 objRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

I gave a custom page size 3*5 inches paper in crystal report, the print is perfect with 2 or 3 items in this invoice, but when I exceed the paper length, it is printing  my report header and footer in the middle of the page and printing the bill, I want this to print with dynamic page length size. I've googled for 3 days but could not find a proper solution to fix my requirements, please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Place your Details In Crystal Report Details Sector.Remove Everything in Page Header.Only Use Report Header ,Report Footer and the Detail Sector..!